# How to change a png image color in a data bound list

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone

I have a bound list which would show different image at each item. 
I know we could change the png image color by doing:

```
<Rectangle Height="100" Width="100" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}">
    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/folder.png" Stretch="None"/>
    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
</Rectangle>
```

But this is for a specified image, what I want to do is to apply the same effect on a data bound image. like:

```
<Image Height="100" Width="100" Source="{Binding IconSource}" Stretch="None"/>
```

Is there anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, so since you can't bind to a ImageBrush, here's a workaround:

```
<Rectangle Width="100"
           Height="100"
           Fill="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
           OpacityMask="{Binding IconSource, Converter={StaticResource ImageToOpacityMaskValueConverter}}" />
```

Using following converter:

```
public class ImageToOpacityMaskValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is Uri)
        {
            var image = new BitmapImage((Uri)value);
            if (image != null)
            {
                var imageBrush = new ImageBrush()
                {
                    ImageSource = image
                };

                return imageBrush;
            }
        }

        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

That said, I would recommend using vector graphics (ie. a  drawing) instead of a image.

Comment: Hello, I've tried your code, but the ImageBrush doesn't inherit from FrameworkElement so it can't be Template Bound or Data Bound.

Comment: I wanted to try your code, but I got this warning: Warning 1 The resource "ImageToOpacityMaskValueConverter" could not be resolved. Where should I put the converter?? Sorry, it seems like a silly question.

Comment: You need to define it as a resource. Example here: http://www.wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html (it's the same for SL, WPF and WP7)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I want to confirm that have you tried this code? I get all code running without error, but I just can't get the image show..

Comment: Yep, works fine. Remember that I designed it to bind against a Uri.

Comment: Worked now! I set the rectangle stretch to None, made the image disappeared. Thanks very much for your reply!